# Unable to add raid drives to Asus z97 machine

Tags: partitioning, raid, asus

I have a Asus z97-a Motherboard and I just installed 2 HGST 4 Terabyte drives. Awesome right?  Except that I cant seem to get the on board ASUS Raid to work?

"Control I" will get me into the Bios and I am able to create a raid.

Then into GPARTED to set up a partition, Except now The drive has a bunch of letters in its name that I did not put there and I cannot access it.

Anyone have any ideas here?

Thanks for your help.

Michael